# Write packet's source ip address into packet's payload during traffic redirection

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, routing

I'm trying to solve this problem. Suppose my Linux machine works as a virtual router. I want that some of the packets received, for example, the ones with source IP Address 192.168.0.1, have their source IP Address rewritten to 10.0.0.1 and, in the same time, the former source IP Address (i.e. 192.168.0.1) is written into the TCP/UDP payload of this same packet.

I was trying to use the iptables function along with the netsed to realize this. However, I don't believe I can do this using these two tools. Another approach I have in mind is to use a virtual switch (e.g. Open vSwitch) to do this; unfortunately, to the best of knowledge, I will have to extend the switch to do this. How could I solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Seems like you're working at the incorrect layer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any tool that can do it for you. Your option would be to write a custom program or do it at Network Layer.

To do it at Network Layer, you can use IP in IP Tunnel. This will encapsulate the original packet in to the new IP Packet while it goes through transit Networks, and then remove the Header on the other end of the tunnel.

https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/tunneling